# Custom Search ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, search, admin

I want to implement a simple search textbox, in which user can search for any content of the site by specifying keyword.

Admin should be able to configure the search results, i.e. he can enable/disable any keyword, so page related to that keywords will not be displayed in search results.

I do have one option in my mind...

*We can put a xml file which is editable by admin, xml file will contain keyword and url related to that keyword, so admin can enable/disable it at anytime.*

But not sure how much reliable it is!

Please Share your Ideas...

Comment: I saw a demonstration some months ago of Truffler.Net which could be used to index your site, you may also add any .net object to the index. Truffler.Net has then been purchased by EPI server and renamed EPI Server Find http://find.episerver.com/ It's not free, you have to pay a fee per month depending on how many documents you index and other features.

Comment: I want a 'simple' spaceship to send me to the moon. Well the word simple is not make it simple. You need to index your pages, save the results, then make the page that search the index and show the results, and still it will be bad... because the results will not the one you dream of. Need a lot of work

Comment: @Aristos: Yes indeed the thought of the spaceship may be simple. Just like: 1. I want a spaceship. 2. The ship should fly me to the moon. But then if you look at the blueprints for building the spaceship it is not at all simple.